# Is it possible to see the dictionary for Words With Friends?

Tags: words-with-friends

Is it possible to see the dictionary used by Words With Friends? Occasionally the game creator includes dictionary updates with updates to the game itself, and it would be nice to know what words have been added or removed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Words With Friends uses the Enhanced North American Benchmark Lexicon (ENABLE), with a few custom additions such as 'Zen' and 'Qi'. The base word list can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetperls-controls/downloads/detail?name=enable1.txt&can=2&q=), but I don't have a source for any of the custom additions at this time.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20120609012115/http://newtoyinc.com/gameswithfriends/support/Words_With_Friends_Rulebook.html)

Answer (score -3):

There are a number of Words with Friends Help site, where they listed all the acceptable and recognized words in Words with Friends.  You can also find the official game rules [in an article I wrote](http://www.streetarticles.com/online-gaming/official-game-rules-in-playing-words-with-friends).

Comment: That's your own article. Not disclosing that sort of thing here can get you flagged as a spammer.