# Words with Friends: played blank tile as blank, glitch?

Tags: words-with-friends

I somehow managed to play a blank tile *as* a blank (6th row, 13th col):

[image]

and got the double word score for TACT.

Is this a glitch, or a legitimate move? The HTML for this tile (note 
that zynga numbers rows starting with 0):

```
<div class="space_13_5 space dw has_tooltip mt  recent"><span class="tile lette\
r-" data-letter-id="0"></span>
```

(It's game number 3950502083 if anyone from zynga's reading this)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't appear to be a bug. If you search for "tact" in the Words With Friends [Dictionary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7162/is-it-possible-to-see-the-dictionary-for-words-with-friends?rq=1), [(direct)](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetperls-controls/downloads/detail?name=enable1.txt&can=2&q=), you'll see that the word "tacts" is also an entry. Although I can't imagine the word tact having a plural for any reason, the blank tile was probably recognized as an S, not as empty space.

Comment: OK, I went back and checked the game, and now there's a little red-dot 16 by the blank tile and the wording above the board states "Barry Carter played TACT for 16 points". The point score is consistent with the blank tile being treated as a 1-point tile, so this answer seems reasonable.